# Getting iOS app to talk to my home server

Tags: python, ios, sockets, networking

Currently, I have a home server in my closet basically doing nothing. It has Ubuntu Server 8.0.4 installed, apache for web development ill be using later, ssh, and python/twisted installed.

Here's the issue:

I created an app to talk to "localhost" port-40, using socket implementation, here is a link of what I did but what I want to develop off of : http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Now connecting to the localhost is no problem but I want to expand this to work with my server.

I implemented the python protocol onto my server and changed the ip address im accessing in the iOS app. Here's the implementation I have, it's exactly the same as the tutorial except for the port i'm accessing.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol

from twisted.internet import reactor

class IphoneChat(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        a = data.split(':')
        print a
        #b = password.split(':')
        #print b
        if len(a) > 1:
            command = a[0]
            content = a[1]
            #username = a[2]
            #password = a[2]

            msg = ""
            #msg2 = ""
            if command == "username":
                self.name = data
                msg = self.name + " has joined"
                #self.name = password
                #msg2 = self.name + " this is his password"
                #print msg

            elif command == "password":
                self.name = data
                msg = self.name + " this is their password"

            elif command == "msg":
                msg = self.name + ": " + data
                print msg
                #msg2 = self.name + ": " + password
                #print msg2

            for c in self.factory.clients:
                c.message(msg)#1, msg2)

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')


factory = Factory()

factory.protocol = IphoneChat #here1#

factory.clients = []

reactor.listenTCP(40, factory)

print "Iphone Chat server started"

reactor.run()
```

So the REAL issue is, I cannot connect clients to my server or something..... I'm sorry but I am very new to networking.

Any opinion will help.

Comment: is the port available on your server?

Comment: I am only able to access my server through an ssh command, ssh usernmae@10.0.0.26, and then im prompted to enter my password and then I enter the ubuntu server which is installed on my desktop in the garage. The desktop is connected to the internet through ethernet hardwired to my router where my main computer is wirelessly accessing from my room.

Answer (score 1):

If you've not established networking communication to your server from the internet before you'll want to establish that you can do that with simple test cases first, there's a lot that can stop traffic from the internet reaching your program on your server.

Is your server connected to the internet through a router? If so, can you communicate with the server from inside the local network (i.e. use the 192.168.xxx.xxx ip address), using something like `netcat` or `telnet`?

If that works you should try from outside the network (i.e. using the other ip address, from [whatismyip.net](http://whatismyip.net) or similar). If you've really no prior experience with networking you may have neglected to set up port forwarding, this is a setting on your router.

There are a lot of tutorials around teaching you how to set up a Ubuntu home server, I suggest learning how to host a (very) simple webpage as a means of learning how to network, this will help a lot with debugging a networked program like the one you're making.

Comment: So when i use "$TELNET 10.0.0.26 80", i get connected to the server, but how do I see this action? on the my homeserver? Also my homeserver is connected to my router through ethernet and my main computer is connected to the same router wirelessly.

Comment: When i use the 'w' command in terminal, it displays the current clients connected to the server but I cannot see the user than logged in using telnet 10.0.0.26 80, which was me on my main computer. I notice my information when i use the ssh login but not when I use telnet. I might be way off on understanding all this but I feel like I am getting connected but don't know to where and how.

Comment: Try something along the lines of http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/nc-command-examples/ i.e. `$ nc -l 2389` on the server and `$ nc 10.0.0.26 2389` from the client, paying particular attention to the port you're using. Some may be open and others closed.